# Multiple ALTER column queries in SQLite with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I need to make some of the columns NOT NULL in the tables in my database. I only then discovered that SQLite has limited ALTER support, and the common workaround is to create a duplicate table and copy the data over.

However this would be a very time consuming task due to the large number of tables I need to change. Since all I'm changing in my SQLAlchemy models is adding `nullable=False` to the column definitions, is there a simple way to apply the change to the current database? I'm working under the assumption that there are no null values in the columns.

Comment: I would check out `sqlalchemy-migrate`  .... I don't use it, normally I just drop tables and rebuild with sqlalchemy, but I looked into it for a more production ready approach

Comment: I looked at it, and I'm hoping there's a solution that won't take as long as setting up sqlalchemy-migrate. Also, I wasn't able to determine if they would fix the lack of ALTER support in SQLite.

Comment: Yes we're already in production so I can't drop tables.

Comment: The quickest way I would probably do it is to backup the current live db, build the new db, write a quick mapping that reads and writes from old db to new db since you already have the original schema, it shouldnt be hard. You'd need to probably get a window to point all apps that use the db to the new db, If thats manageable

Comment: I guess that's probably the quickest way to do it.